# BuddyPress and namespacing

Tags: plugin-development, buddypress, autoloading

I'm using PSR-4 autoloading and namespacing for a new plugin. However, because my plugin is namespaced (and all it's classes are), I can't seem to extend a BuddyPress class (BP_Attachment) successfully as it doesn't want to pass the `if ( class_exists( 'BP_Attachment', false ) )` check. I've tried to require it, "use" it, and more. Nothing works. Since BuddyPress doesn't use namespacing am I out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `if ( class_exists( '\BP_Attachment', false ) )`?

Could be that you need to tell PHP that the class is in the global namespace

Comment: I tried this last night, but just to confirm I have it right,

I have 
`namespace PLUGIN_NAME;
use \BP_Attachment;
if  ( class_exists( '\BP_Attachment', false ) ) ...`